# Vectorized Scalar | Is there such thing?

Tags: real-analysis, operations-research

Ok, So I am trying to look for the branch of mathametics that deals with scalar property such as surface which shows vector like qualities. So for analogy I am looking for a scalar area such that any path (vector) taken inside that area will result in closed circuit path much like Nescar racing circuit as well as satisfy the path length constraint. So the following is the objective:

$$\textrm{minimize}\ A\   \ \ \ \  \textrm{s.t}\\
\Sigma_{i=0}^{k}\ \sqrt{{(x_i-x_{i+1})}^2+{(y_i-y_{i+1})}^2}\ \le N
\\ x_0 =x_k
\\ y_0 =y_k$$

So basically the area must be something like a road layout (not necessarily long rectangular surface but arbitrary shape) that makes a circuit such that any path within that road is closed (arrive same destination where you started) . So is there any such thing that determines such surface such that  the surface acts as a bounding box inside which any path that is constructed is a closed circuit. Again the notion of the path is that U-turns are not allowed and path must be smooth otherwise we can make zig-zag path and U-turns resulting in tiny surface. Illustration of such surface is as follows:
[image]

In summary instead of doing this the hardway as i mentioned is there any functional or anything branch of mathematics that solves this in much comprehensive way such as dealing with the surface directly so surface acts as a path (instead of explicitly describing a path within a surface as I did in my example)?

Comment: If your area $A$ contains a small disc then within that disc you can draw closed paths having arbitrarily large lengths. Therefore your condition $\ldots\leq N$ does not admit interesting areas.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter correct. That is why I mentioned no U-turns in my statement. Moreover, the notion is that we have non-holonomic body that is traveling inside such surface. The question I am asking is can is there any branch of mathametics that tend to solve such problems directly by having tensor-like object (tensor also uses idea of surface, but in tensor surface is used to separate the vectors)

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I want to use surface as a "rough path" by computing such surfaces directly. So the surface gets narrow to a curve in certain area, if I wanna remove the degrees of freedom for say someone walking along the surface and the surface broadens if I wanna increase the degree of freedom so the person can move walk little freely with little extra degrees of freedom.

Comment: I don't understand how a "bounding box" could force paths to be closed. Pick two distinct points inside the eligible area and connect them with a path inside the area. The path is not closed because it does not end where it starts. What I am misunderstanding?

Comment: @prubin, I think the notion of "bounding box" here might be misunderstood as well as my "loose" definition of what I am looking for. To answer your comment. Consider that you are in a bicycle and driving across the corridor "you are now non-holonomic body" . The width of corridor is such that you have some degrees of freedom to sway little left and little right but you cant turn because the corridor is slightly less then turning radius of your bicycle. Nevertheless you still have freedom to sway right or left. In some-places the corridor is so narrow that it barely fits you.

Comment: This corridor is now a closed circuit. So you will arrive where you started. Now the notion is that the surface of the corridor as shown in my question is scalar, yet for a holonomic body it acts as a vector because it dictates the direction such body "could" take. Now I just want to abstract the notion of such body to see if there is a branch of mathematics that can deal with vectorized surface directly.

Comment: So this surface could be though of some sort of gaussian path, the path is more constrained at some places (less variance) while the path is less constrained at other places (large variance) so not "explicitly" forcing me to stay at given path but I have some room for the freedom. So it is explicitly not a path but it is behaving like a "path". Does this makes sense?

Comment: I'm not understanding the meaning of a "scalar surface", nor of "acting like a vector". It sounds as if the variance is a form of "width" of the surface. To extend your bicycle analogy, if you keep riding indefinitely, is the question whether you will eventually return to where you started, or whether you will ever (with some probability) revisit a point, or something else?

Comment: Yes the variance is a form of a width of the surface. So essentially such surface will make you keep cycling in a loop. This was just an analogy to give a notion that how a surface can act as a vectorized path given additional constraint of the object being unable to turn and can go only ahead. Now if the surface was infinite rectangle or any infinte arbitrary shape then such surface will cease to act like a vectorized path. It is only when a surface assumes certain properties it acts as a vectorized path. More like a surface that constraint your degrees of freedom. Does it make any sense?